# How do I calculate the ground state energy of a number of protons in a 3D potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

I came up with a question in a previous physics exam of my professor that I for some reason can't seem to be able to answer, and I'd really appreciate some help in case he gives me the same question when I take the exam.
The question is:

> The eigenstates of the energy of a particle in a 3D potential well are $E=b(n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)$, where $b>0$ and $n_1$,$n_2$,$n_3=1,2,3,...$ Assume that we have $14$ protons inside the well. What is the value of the energy in the ground state?

My attempt at a solution was as follows:
The lowest energy value of the system is: $E_{111}=3b$ with a degeneracy of $1$. So, I can place up to 2 protons there (with spin of $+1/2$ and $-1/2$). The second highest energy level is $E_{112}=6b$ with a degeneracy of 3 (|2,1,1>, |1,2,1>, |1,1,2>) so I can place up to 6 protons here. Finally, the third highest energy level is $E_{221}=9b$ with a triple degeneracy again (|221>, |122>, |212>), so again, up to 6 protons. This covers up all the 14 protons, and I would get a total energy of $E_{total}=2\times3b+6\times6b+6\times9b=96b$.

Problem is, as this is a multiple-choice question, my options are: $106b$, $128b$, $150b$, $172b$, and $184b$. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The $E$ are eigenvalues, not eigenstates. Sus.